# FIXED Trying to Pause/Play MP3 file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio

Hoping to have two buttons, one to "Pause" one to "Play" the MP3 audio file. Buttons show but do not pause/play the audio, Aswell as the audio does not play whatsoever. Here's my code I'm using. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Loadingscreen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls id="song">
        <source src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause</button>
    <div class="slides slowFade">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image3.png" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x = document.getElementById("song"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. do you put the audio next to the HTML file?

Comment: As in File path of the mp3 file? I have everything right now in a `html` folder with css file, js file. So should be /html/music.mp3 correct?

Comment: Messed around with the file path `html/music.mp3` and `music.mp3` still haven't gotten it to play with the buttons.

Comment: Open your developer tools and see the `console` tab. Is there any error there?

Comment: I see these errors while viewing the console in developer tools.                      
                                                                                                                           
   Uncaught ReferenceError: playAudio is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14:49)
index.html:15
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: pauseAudio is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:15:50)
4index.html:14
       
       Uncaught ReferenceError: playAudio is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14:49)

Comment: It seems your js file is is not loaded in your HTML file. can you share your whole HTML file?

Comment: I've updated the post with the full HTML. Also, now seem to get this error in dev tools console. script.js:4 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')
    at playAudio (script.js:4:5)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14:49) index.html:16 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: pauseAudio is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:16:50) appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load your js file after loading the document.

You should put the script at the end of the HTML file. You use `var x = document.getElementById("song");`  to get the DOM element but the element is not loaded yet as your script is on the top of the page so you can change the code this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Loadingscreen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls id="song">
        <source src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause</button>
    <div class="slides slowFade">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image3.png" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt="img"/ height="100%" width="100px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- the DOM will be available here -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a good practice to load JS file at the end of the file that makes the user see HTML faster.

If for any reason you cant load the js file at the end of the page you can change your JS file this way:

```
function playAudio() { 
const x = document.getElementById("song"); 
  x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
const x = document.getElementById("song"); 
  x.pause(); 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Forgot all about that when linking the JavaScript file! Used to throwing it at the top of html file. Seems to be running perfectly now. Buttons do pause/play music. Thank you again! Will edit the post to [FIXED] So anyone comes by dealing with similar issue, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using javascript for audio?
such as

```
var myAudio = new Audio(myAudioLink)
```

then doing

```
function playMyAudio() {
myAudio.play()
}
function pauseMyAudio() {
myAudio.pause()
}
```

i am glad to help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip, tried this, didn't see a solution. Was thinking it may be a file path mistake but after adding the folder into the path I still seem to have no audio play with and without the buttons.